# switch off logging for specific mongo database

Tags: mongodb

I have three MongoDB databases and total six collections under them. There is a TTL index created on these collections so documents expire after 10 seconds. These collections get documents every millisecond.

The problem I have is logging. MongoDB Log fills up due to all these writes. I can't set quiet=true in mongod config file because it will switch off logging on all other databases where logging is required.

Is there any way to control logging per mongodb database or any better way to control logging.

Thank You.